# Problems with opening files using nodejs and id3

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I'm having problems opening files with certain characters in nodejs using id3js.

The file i'm trying to read is `"14 What'z Ya Phone # (Feat. Danny Bo.mp3"`

The error i'm getting is `/14%20What'z%20Ya%20Phone%20 net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND`

As you can see, its cutting off at # in the original file name. What steps do i have to take to make sure node uses the entire filename when looking for the file.

Comment: Just a suggestion: have you tried URL encoding the # as %23? Does this work?

Comment: Yeah that worked! Is that just for # or is there a list of conversions i would need to make.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some classic characters that should not be in urls. Examples are: ? # @ / \ : and %. I think / and \ are obvious why not (file paths). ? is used for get requests. # is used as an shortcut to an id on a page. An email-address uses @'s, also ftp can use @. You can specify a port in a url bij :. % is used for url encodings.

These characters escaping will probably work, (most of those characters aren't allowed in filenames by your filesystem):

```
? -> %3F
# -> %23
@ -> %40
/ -> %2F
\ -> %5C
: -> %3A
% -> %25
```

In my linux mint I can rename a file to: '?#@:\.txt'. You can experiment which characters you need te replace.

**Note** If you're replacing in javascript don't forget to set a global flag: `"".replace(/\?/g, "%3F")`.